# System.err java log location in ColdFusion

Tags: java, coldfusion, logging

I have some ColdFusion code which calls a function in a Java class via:

```
<cfset object = CreateObject("java","org.prog.jar.Class")>
<cfset object.Method()>
```

If an error is thrown in the Java class it writes the error to the Java error stream:

```
System.err.println(e.getMessage());
```

Can someone tell me what happens to this stream in ColdFusion and whether it is written to a file or is accessible in any other way?

Thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default to `C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\logs\` for single instance or `C:\JRun4\logs` for multi instance.

Check ["Log Directory"](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf3638e6-7fe0.html) in your CF Administrator.

I'm not sure, but I'd say it's either in `application.log` or `exception.log` or both.

Comment: Henry it is C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\logs\ not C:\ColdFusion9\logs.

Comment: Never mind. I see you edited your response to correct the path.

Answer (score 1):

- If the exception is being caught, it should *not* be logged to `application.log` or `exception.log`
- Otherwise, for a single instance, try the default `C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\logs\` directory for check the latest `coldfusion-outX.log` file (they rotate). Note: The location of the logs can vary.

Btw: You can always test it out from CF using:

```
<cfset System = createObject("java", "java.lang.System")>
<cfset System.err.println("where does this message end up?")>
```

Comment: Down voter, care to comment? The answer is absolutely correct. Not mention, given that both answers say the same thing, I am curious why you down voted one, but not the other.